# How can I fix malformed error for date using java?

Tags: java

I want to parse the date in Java. But it throws the error I shared below. I mentioned the codes I wrote. What should I do to prevent this error?

**Exception**

```
15.06.2020 17:13:39,885 ERROR tr.com.analysis.DerivedDataCalculator calculateDerivedDatas 139: Field Banking relation period  with path: null, formula: 
curDateDiff(#//CustomerBasedRelation/CustomerSince, currentDate#), error: Invalid format: "2020-06-15" is malformed at "20-06-15"
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2020-06-15" is malformed at "20-06-15"
        at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:945)
        at tr.com..analysis.DerivedDataCalculator.dateComparision(DerivedDataCalculator.java:207)
        at tr.com.analysis.DerivedDataCalculator.calculateDerivedData(DerivedDataCalculator.java:109)
        at tr.com.analysis.CptyDerivedDataCalculator.calculateDerivedDatas(CptyDerivedDataCalculator.java:121)
```

**Convert.java**

```
public static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT_STRING = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_STRING = "dd.MM.yyyy";
```

**DerivedDataCalculator.java**

```
private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

private DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(Convert.DATE_FORMAT_STRING);
```

**Usage of dtf**

```
for (String expression : expressions) {
    String extractedDateStr = null;
    if (expression.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("currentDate")) {
        extractedDateStr = sdf.format(new Date());
    } else {
        extractedDateStr = (String) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xml, XPathConstants.STRING);
    }

    if (order == 1) {
        date1 = StringUtils.isBlank(extractedDateStr) ? null : dtf.parseDateTime(extractedDateStr).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
    } else {
        date2 = StringUtils.isBlank(extractedDateStr) ? null : dtf.parseDateTime(extractedDateStr).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
    }
    order++;
}
```

Comment: `yy-MM-dd` format

Comment: I strongly suggest that you stop using `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, for they are obsolete. Use classes from the `java.time` package instead.

Comment: @sidgate  How does he understand the year using the yy-MM-dd format? eg 2019. Does it accept 20 or 19?

Comment: what is the value of `(String) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xml, XPathConstants.STRING);` ?

Comment: Your code is too disjointed to understand.  Please write a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Something that we can cut and paste into a file, compile, run, and see the problem that you are talking about.  It will save everyone a lot of time ....

Answer (score 1):

```
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_STRING = "dd.MM.yyyy";

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2020-06-15" is malformed at "20-06-15"
```

Well, "2020-06-15" is not actually in the format of "dd.MM.yyyy", is it?